# How to correctly capitalize words inside of brackets/parentheses in article names and book titles?

Tags: grammar, parentheses, titles, book-title

How do I correctly capitalize words inside of brackets/parentheses in names and titles?

A few examples:

> Captain America (untold stories)
> Captain America (Untold Stories)
>
> Madonna (written by E. Cales in 1998)
> Madonna (Written by E. Cales in 1998)
>
> My Summer Vacation (with my family)
> My Summer Vacation (With My Family)
> My Summer Vacation (With my family)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're qualifying as parts of the *title* vs subtext, with consideration to important words.  For the examples you gave, I would use:

`Captain America (Untold Stories)` because "Untold Stories" appears to be a part of the title, and both of those words are significant.

`Madonna (written by E. Cales in 1998)` because the 'written by' is not part of the title.

`My Summer Vacation (With my Family)` could be argued as `(With My Family)` - essentially, the "my" in this case is acting as a bridge - like "the" or "of" in `Phantom of the Opera` - they are not significant words, but they are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Helpful's helpful answer - I would use document formatting as well if possible to differentiate titles from other info, e.g.:

> *Captain America (Untold Stories)*
>
> *Madonna* (written by E. Cales in 1998)
>
> *My Summer Vacation (With My Family)*

Or, add quotation marks:

> "Captain America (Untold Stories)"
>
> "Madonna" (written by E. Cales in 1998)
>
> "My Summer Vacation (With My Family)"